# Bootstrap Modal disappears when used with Navigation Wizard

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, wizard

I have an issue with Bootstrap Modal. I am using Bootstrap3.x for Modal and BootstrapWizard for custom navigation wizard. So both the libraries are necessary. When I click on Modal it disappears automatically. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. My initial HTML code looks like this

```
<button class="btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPostModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Add Posts</button>
```

But I modified this to

```
<button class="btn-default" id="myButton">Add Posts</button>
```

and wrote a jQuery function to handle onclick action

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#myButton").click(function()
            {
                $("#addPostModal").modal("toggle");
            });
        });
```

In brief, I removed the toggle functionality from HTML and added toggle method. We can also remove "toggle" from onclick() function, it doesn't make any difference.

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#myButton").click(function()
                {
                    $("#addPostModal").modal();
                });
            });
```